# Insert html inside text area

Tags: javascript, html

I have

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
```

When i insert html

```
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').value = "<p>Content</p>";
```

The html does not get rendered inside the `<textarea />`

Is there a way to render html inside textarea?

Answer (score 8):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements (like an array), so you have to specify the index of the one you want. If you only have one use [0]

```
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = "<p>Content</p>";
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xjr9do7m/)**

Note that you can't render HTML in a textarea though, only text.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot render HTML inside a text area as it is for input. You can only render text